# Add HTML code into Image Map using JQuery or other tools

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

Add HTML code into Image Map using JQuery or other tools

I want to achieve following result [click here](https://wwwimages2.adobe.com/multimedia/en_us/get/reader/Acrobat/1000x463_hover_tooltips_as2.swf)

I have a image with clickable elements but I want to add blinking element next to every clickable elemnt , for examnle [this one](http://codepen.io/magnus16/pen/pnGAB)

```
<map id="ImageMapsCom-image-maps-2014-02-21-023745" name="map"> 
  <area id="conditioner" shape="poly" coords="1552.0333251953125,186,1551.0333251953125,203,1559.0333251953125,211,1626.0333251953125,213,1627.0333251953125,188" alt="Montarea condiționerului" title="Montarea condiționerului" target="_self" href="http://santehmaster.md/index.php?option=com_content&view=article&id=101&Itemid=771&lang=en"     />

  <area id="calorifere" shape="poly" coords="1573.0333251953125,289,1630.0333251953125,292,1630.0333251953125,328,1573.0333251953125,325" alt="Montarea caloriferelor" title="Montarea caloriferelor" target="_self" href="http://santehmaster.md/index.php?option=com_content&view=article&id=89&Itemid=737&lang=en"     />

  <area id="stingator" shape="poly" coords="1519,400,1520,407,1522,443,1535,445,1533,406" alt="Montarea sistemului de stingere cu hidranți" title="Montarea sistemului de stingere cu hidranți" target="_self" href="http://santehmaster.md/index.php?option=com_content&view=article&id=216&Itemid=872&lang=en"     />
</map>
```

it would be nice to insert such code

```
<map id="ImageMapsCom-image-maps-2014-02-21-023745" name="map"> 
  <span class="beacon"></span>

  <area id="conditioner" shape="poly" coords="1552.0333251953125,186,1551.0333251953125,203,1559.0333251953125,211,1626.0333251953125,213,1627.0333251953125,188" alt="Montarea condiționerului" title="Montarea condiționerului" target="_self" href="http://santehmaster.md/index.php?option=com_content&view=article&id=101&Itemid=771&lang=en"     />

  <span class="beacon"></span>
  <area id="calorifere" shape="poly" coords="1573.0333251953125,289,1630.0333251953125,292,1630.0333251953125,328,1573.0333251953125,325" alt="Montarea caloriferelor" title="Montarea caloriferelor" target="_self" href="http://santehmaster.md/index.php?option=com_content&view=article&id=89&Itemid=737&lang=en"     />

  <span class="beacon"></span>
  <area id="stingator" shape="poly" coords="1519,400,1520,407,1522,443,1535,445,1533,406" alt="Montarea sistemului de stingere cu hidranți" title="Montarea sistemului de stingere cu hidranți" target="_self" href="http://santehmaster.md/index.php?option=com_content&view=article&id=216&Itemid=872&lang=en"     />
</map>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here is the solution:

1. First of all I include script to resize image, and area coordinates on window resize.

   ```
   <script>
   window.onload = function () {
       var ImageMap = function (map, img) {
               var n,
                   areas = map.getElementsByTagName('area'),
                   len = areas.length,
                   coords = [],
                   previousWidth = 1921;
               for (n = 0; n < len; n++) {
                   coords[n] = areas[n].coords.split(',');
               }
               this.resize = function () {
                   var n, m, clen,
                       x = img.offsetWidth / previousWidth;
                   for (n = 0; n < len; n++) {
                       clen = coords[n].length;
                       for (m = 0; m < clen; m++) {
                           coords[n][m] = Math.round(parseInt(coords[n][m], 10) * x);
                       }
                       areas[n].coords = coords[n].join(',');
                   }
                   previousWidth = document.body.clientWidth;
                   return true;
               };
               window.onresize = this.resize;
           },
           imageMap = new ImageMap(document.getElementById('ImageMapsCom-image-maps-2014-02-21-023745'), document.getElementById('Image-Maps-Com-image-maps-2014-02-21-023745'));
       imageMap.resize();
       return;
   }
   ```
2. Then add following HTML before closing `</map>` tag:

> ```
> <div class="blinking">
>     <span class="beacon position1"></span>
>     <span class="beacon position2"></span>
>     <span class="beacon position3"></span>
>     <span class="beacon position4"></span>
>     <span class="beacon position5"></span>
>     <span class="beacon position6"></span>
>     <span class="beacon position7"></span>
>     <span class="beacon position8"></span>
>     <span class="beacon position9"></span>
>     <span class="beacon position10"></span>
> </div>
> ```

FINALLY  Add yours styles CSS

Answer (score 1):

just get the offset of the area element and add the span on the same offset:

```
var offset=$("#conditioner").offset();
$("body").append("<span class='bacon'></span>").css({
  position:'absolute',
  top: offset.top,
  left: offset.left
});
```

Remember to recalculate the offset on browser resize.